# Android 13 media projection screenshot is black

Tags: android, android-mediaprojection

I am having an error with the media projection and taking screenshots but only with android 13, sometimes they come out black, but not always. I have tried to put a delay (up to 5 seconds) to see if maybe the android system was the cause of it, but it still happens, any help is appreciated. I did search the site, but nothing comes up with android 13 issue.

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(size);
final int width = size.x, height = size.y;

final ImageReader imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 1);

imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(reader -> {
    //-> Stop our media projection just in case it is running
    mediaProjection.stop();

    Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
    if (image != null){
      Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
      ByteBuffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer();
      int pixelStride = planes[0].getPixelStride(), rowStride = planes[0].getRowStride(), rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * width;
      bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width + rowPadding / pixelStride, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
      bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer); 

      String fileName = "Screenshot_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
      String destinationPath = this.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/screenshots/" + fileName;

      File imageFile = new File(destinationPath);
      FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
      int quality = 100;
      bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
      outputStream.flush();
      outputStream.close();

      String mediaPath = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + File.separator + "Screenshots/myapp" + File.separator;

      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
      values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 0);
      values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, mediaPath);
      values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
      values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE, imageFile.length());
      values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
      Uri path = this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

      OutputStream imageOutStream = this.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(path);

      bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, imageOutStream);
      if (imageOutStream != null) {
         imageOutStream.flush();
         imageOutStream.close();
      }

      if (image != null) { image.close(); }
      mediaProjection.stop();
      if (reader != null){ reader.close(); }
    }
}, null);
```

Comment: First, read the API change of android 13, check the related change if has. Then, the code here is good to debug, you should use `log` to show some break point, Ex: the exception when flush or close stream, the `path` result of `insert` method, or even the image, bitmap value... I think we can found the problem somewhere here.

Comment: This problem also causes by the Emulator device(*If you test your app in an emulator*). I was face this issue when I tried my app to take screenshots in the android 13 `emulator`. I suggest you try your app in *Real Mobile Device* of android 13. Maybe this issue is also the same as mine.

Comment: @MDEV this is being tested on a real device, I never use an emulator because of those issues. It appears it is just a bug with android 13 as other developers are also having this issue with their apps.

Answer (score 6):

In my testing and observation, there're two issues when using ImageReader with media projection on Android 13

First, the callback result of `setOnImageAvailableListener` sometimes returns buffer with empty pixels. So we can just wait for the next image until we get a **non-empty** bitmap

```
imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener({ imageReader ->
    val image = imageReader.acquireLatestImage()
    // ... get buffer here
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenWidth + rowPadding / pixelStride, screenHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer)

    // IMPORTANT!
    val isEmptyBitmap = bitmap.isEmptyBitmap()
    if (isEmptyBitmap) {
        // don't stop the listener and let the imageReader continue to run so that we can get next round of image buffer
    } else {
        // save bitmap to file
    }

    }, Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()))
```

the isEmptyBitmap() is just an extension of Bitmap:

```
fun Bitmap.isEmptyBitmap(): Boolean {
    val emptyBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, config)
    return this.sameAs(emptyBitmap)
}
```

The second issue is that, the `OnImageAvailableListener` sometimes doesn't even callback!
In this case, I set a timeout to wait for the result, and when timed-out, recreate the VirtualDisplay object from the same MediaProjection instance and it just works.

I'm using kotlin coroutine so the code snippet may look like:

```
retry(10) {
    val imageVirtualDisplay = createVirtualDisplay(...)
    try {
        withTimeout(100) {
            // awaitImageAvailable will suspend here to get the non-empty bitmap
            val bitmap = imageReader.awaitImageAvailable(screenWidth, screenHeight)
            // save bitmap to file
        }
    } finally {
        Timber.d("screenshot imageVirtualDisplay release")
        imageVirtualDisplay?.release()
    }
}
```

the implementation of `awaitImageAvailable`:

```
suspend fun ImageReader.awaitImageAvailable(screenWidth: Int, screenHeight: Int): Bitmap =
suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
    setOnImageAvailableListener({ imageReader ->

        val image = imageReader.acquireLatestImage() ?: throw Error("get screen image result failed")

        val planes = image.planes
        val buffer = planes[0].buffer

        val pixelStride = planes[0].pixelStride
        val rowStride = planes[0].rowStride
        val rowPadding: Int = rowStride - pixelStride * screenWidth
        var bitmap =
            Bitmap.createBitmap(screenWidth + rowPadding / pixelStride, screenHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer)
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)
        image.close()

        if (!bitmap.isEmptyBitmap()) {
            Timber.d("image not empty")
            setOnImageAvailableListener(null, null)
            cont.resume(bitmap)
        } else {
            Timber.w("image empty")
        }
    }, Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()))

    cont.invokeOnCancellation { setOnImageAvailableListener(null, null) }
}
```

Comment: Is it not a problem that you call `createVirtualDisplay(...)` before you set up the listener with `setOnImageAvailableListener`? What if a callback comes before the listener is set up?

Comment: Might be, but this issue only happened on android 13

Comment: it work for me on android 13